# Angled brackets in a knitr rinline expression

Tags: r, knitr

I'm running into an issue with the rinline pattern for HTML templates in knitr:

```
inline.code : chr "<!--\\s*rinline\\s*([^>]*)\\s*-->"
```

The nature of this pattern means that knitr doesn't recognise any rinline expression that itself contains angled brackets. E.g:

```
<ul>
<!--rinline I(paste("<li>",gene.black.list,"</li>",collapse="",sep="")) -->
</ul>
```

Is not evaluated by the engine as I'd like (gene.black.list is just a character vector, hopefully the intent of my code is clear). To get round this I'm doing the following:

```
<!--begin.rcode echo=F
  tagged.gene.black.list = paste("<li>",gene.black.list,"</li>",collapse="",sep="")
  end.rcode-->

<ul>
<!--rinline I(tagged.gene.black.list) -->
</ul>
```

Which works, but seems a little unsatisfactory with the creation of the superfluous extra variable and the multiple code blocks. Is there a smarter, neater way I am missing?

Comment: Yes I need to change the regular expression, but I do not know what is the correct one at the moment. Ideally I want the match to stop once it sees `-->`, and that sounds like a non-greedy match, but `'<!--\\s*rinline(.*?)-->'` does not solve the problem (I guess PCRE should be able to solve it). So I need help too.

Comment: Ah, OK. Thanks for the answer (and great tool) anyway - at least I'm not missing something obvious!

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem should be [fixed now](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/commit/fc2777d7764ba8a50a9855b4dcfe81768532c2bf) on Github. Please [install](https://github.com/yihui/knitr#readme) the development version from Github. Basically I changed `<!--\\s*rinline\\s*([^>]*)\\s*-->` to `<!--\\s*rinline(.+?)-->`.